# Создание модели в Django и встроенное редактирование связанных записей

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin, django-model

Не получается вывести связанные записи в панели администратора Django. Помогите пожалуйста с models и выводом связанных записей в admin.
(Преподаватель->Предметы->Вид занятия. К примеру: преподаватель1: русский язык (Лекция, Экзамен), Преподаватель2: математика(лекция, практическое занятие, экзамен), физика (лекция)

models:

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
 
class ClassB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    classA= models.ManyToManyField('ClassA')

class ClassC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    classA= models.ManyToManyField('ClassA')
    classB= models.ManyToManyField('ClassB')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам помогут `InlineModelAdmin` объекты - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Но в Django доступен только 1 уровень вложенности для админки. Для многоуровнего отображения придется использовать приложения вроде `django_nested_admin` - https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Спасибо. Я не знал, что можно использовать только один уровень вложенности в admin. Воспользуюсь приложением

Answer (score -1):

пробовали ли вы использовать функцию **def **str**(self)** для каждой уже созданной модели?
Примерно код будет выглядить вот так

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ClassB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    classA= models.ManyToManyField('ClassA')
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, ({})'.format(self.name, self.ClassA.all())
```

и так далее

Comment: и чем это поможет в решении вопроса?

Comment: Это понятно. Но проблема состоит в том, что не получается отобразить в панели admin больше одного уровня вложенности. «Преподаватель» и «предмет» вывести получается, а вывести  ещё и «вид занятия» не получается. Спасибо, но мне уже ответили на вопрос.